# How to export the environment of Python project

Tags: python, dependencies, pycharm, project, python-venv

I am using Pycharm Community Edition 2019.2.. I imported a Python project from another computer. I just copied the files and then created a new project the directory. There are multiple modules that are imported in this project that I have not installed on my computer. I want to know what is the best way to automatically manage all the dependencies of this project.

I created a virtual environment(venv) in the original project. Can you export this somehow? Is this even the right path to solve this problem? The virtual is supposed to manage dependencies, though I haven't read anything about exporting settings, it mostly about isolating dependencies and settings. I've been looking at conda and pipenv as well, but I focusing on virtual environment before I try to go laterally in problem solving.

Comment: Concider using python ```requirements.txt``` https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/

Comment: Do you think at the hidden _.idea_ folder of PyCharm?

Comment: `pip freeze` on the environment you created the initial project. Then you can just copy them to a `requirements.txt` file and run on the new environment `pip install -r requirements.txt`